# A question on normal subgroups of prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I’ve encountered the following problem whilst helping a colleague study for comprehensive exams, and I really have no idea where to start with it:

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $H\lhd G$ be a normal subgroup of prime index $p$.  For a given $h\in H$, suppose that $\left|c\ell_G(h)\right|=m$, where $c\ell_G(h)$ is the conjugacy class of $h$ in $G$.  Show that $\left|c\ell_H(h)\right|\in\left\{m,\frac{m}{p}\right\}$.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thoughts:

Let $C=C(h)=\{g \in G | ghg^{-1}=h \}$ Then $[G:C]=m$ and the question is what is $[H:H\cap C]$.

Now $[G:H][H:H\cap C]=[G:C][C:H\cap C]$
so $$[H:H\cap C]=\frac{[G:C][C:H\cap C]}{[G:H]}=\frac{m[C:H\cap C]}{p}$$

So we want to see that $[C:H\cap C]=1,p$

However by the third isomorphism theorem

$$[C:H\cap C]=[HC:H]$$ and $HC=H$ or $HC=G$.